# AngularJS: Reuse markup for editing many properties of an object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object with a lot of properties (all of type number). I want to edit these properties so for every property I have an example markup:

```
  <div>
    propertyA: <input type="number" step="0.1" ng-model="configuration.propertyA" required>
  </div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EFCNjLIFJVEZE7CDqzrl)

I don't want to repeat the markup for every property. I would like to use ng-repeat or custom directive, but I don't know how to deal with *ng-model="..."*.

Something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="property in properties">
  {{property.???}}: <input type="number" step="0.1" ng-model="property.???" required>
</div>
```

or custom directive (I know how to transclude static text but what with *ng-model*):

```
<my-directive input-value="PropertyA???">PropertyA: </my-directive>
```

EDIT (maybe will explain more):

I have an configuration object from Server. I don't want to repeat markup I have at the top of the question. I want to have markup once and then loop for every property, so every property will be edited. At the end I want to post configuration back to server.

Comment: I don't really get it, can you explain it better ?

Comment: I explained the use case. Did it help anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to do using directive.

```
app.directive('myInput', function() {
  return {
    restict: 'EA',
    template: '<input type="number" step="0.1" ng-model="value">',
    scope: {
      value: '=',
    },

  }
})
```

Markup:

```
<span my-input value="configuration.weight"></span>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/M9o5A8JYnQeDvhjWDCKU

Answer (score 0):

following the obj you have in your plunkr, it'd just be

```
<div ng-repeat="item in configuration">
  {{item}} <input type="number" step="0.1" ng-model="item" required>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/k1qXyANKRAHJs5drTmXt?p=preview

Comment: It does not update the original object. See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/jMOyMbPVFrykBIAVijd5

Answer (score 0):

$scope.configuration = {
    propertyA: $scope.(NgModel-Name) <----

}
 Instead of value put this $scope, it is called 2 way binding. 
And use ng-value to put init value of items. Do you get it ?

Comment: <form>
      <div ng-repeat="item in configuration">
          {{property.Obiekt1}}<input type="number" step="0.1" ng-model="property.Obiekt1" required>
      </div>

And in js file
$scope.configuration = {
    "property":$scope.Obiekt1
    
    // much, much more
  }

Comment: it should be conected with ng-model ! I gave you code just repalce it

Comment: If you could replace it in the plunker and show it works, it would be great. Otherwise I don't know how to use your solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59735/discussion-between-krzysztof-morcinek-and-mto).